Ошибка сегментирования (образ памяти сброшен на диск) Linux
При исполнении данного кода выскакивает ошибка:
Ошибка сегментирования (образ памяти сброшен на диск)

Код:
extern printf

section .data
    
    first   db  "A",0
    second  db  "B",0
    third   db  "C",0
    fourth  db  "D",0
    fifth   db  "E",0
    sixth   db  "F",0
    seventh db  "G",0
    eighth  db  "H",0
    ninth   db  "I",0
    tenth   db  "J",0
    
    fmt1    db  "The string is: %s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s",10,0
    fmt2    db  "PI = %f",10,0
    pi      dq  3.14
section .bss
section .text
    global main
main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp,rsp
    
        mov rdi,fmt1
        mov rsi,first
        mov rdx,second
        mov rcx,third
        mov r8,fourth
        mov r9,fifth
        
        push tenth
        push ninth
        push eighth
        push seventh
        push sixth
        mov rax,0
        call printf 
        
        and rsp,0xfffffffffffffff0
        
        movsd xmm0,[pi]
        mov rax,1
        mov rdi,fmt2
        call printf       
    
        leave
        ret


Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
